# Font won't render properly on IOS devices. I don't have woff files, just ttf

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts

I can't figure it out. The file which I downloaded from google font, it doesn't have other formats. Just ttf file. It runs fine on google browser. Do you need to use different fonts or there is alternative way to fix? Any help would be appreciated. Using this font:https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cairo+Play

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: "CairoPlay";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/CairoPlay-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "CairoPlay";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/CairoPlay-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "CairoPlay";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/CairoPlay-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

[image: That's what I'm getting on iPhone]

Comment: Run them to a web font generator like FontSquirrel and use that, it fixes any compatibility issues that might arise across browsers. Or just include them from google's CDN.

Comment: @somethinghere FontSquirrel says that the file is corrupted or something. I'm pretty sure it's not corrupted. I downloaded from google font itself.

Comment: I'll be honest, that seems to require quite a bit of knowledge on fonts to know why it is corrupted. Try initially with the google import itself and see if at least that works?

Comment: @somethinghere I tried import it directly instead of doing font-face. It's working fine now. So strange though.